# What is the difference between Cloudinary and Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, cloudinary

What is the difference between Cloudinary and Carrierwave, and if they're different, how does one complement the other? (I am planning to use these in a Rails 5.0.2 application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary is a service for storing images and other media files, and accepts various upload parameters, as well as URL parameters for on-the-fly processing.

CarrierWave is a Ruby library for attaching files, which means it will upload given files to a storage backend (filesystem, S3, Google Cloud etc), and write only the file identifier into the record column.

CarrierWave can use Cloudinary as just another storage backend, and utilize Cloudinary's on-the-fly processing and other features, which is useful if you don't want to process images yourself. CarrierWave can also use another storage backend (filesystem, S3, Google Cloud etc), but most of them are just "dumb object storages" without processing capabilities. Similarly, you can use Cloudinary without CarrierWave, but then you need to implement behaviour for attaching uploaded files to database records yourself.